# window.opener call function gives me a document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

I have the following code on parent window

**Parent Window**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Pop-up call 
 function show_popup()
    {
        var f = window.open("./show_my_popup.php", "mytitle", "width=550, height=500, scrollbars=yes");
    }

 //Call Back from Child Window function


  function GetChildWindowInfo(myval)
   {
    document.getElementById('selecteditem').value = myval;

   }
 </script>
```

And this is the child window part of the code passing value to parent window

**Child window**

```
//Drop down Menu

<select id='selecteditem' name='select_item'>

<?php
foreach($each_query_item as $key => $value) {
echo "  <option value='$value' ";
if($_POST['select_item] == $key) echo "selected";
echo ">$value </option>\n";
}
?>

</select>

//Once you select item click here 

 <input type="button" name="submitbutton" value=<?php xl('Click Me','e','\'','\'');?> onclick="javascript:return SendValueToParent();" />


 <script type="text/javascript">

 function SendValueToParent()
{
    var myval = document.getElementById('selecteditem').value;
    window.opener.GetChildWindowInfo(myval);
    window.close();
    return false;
}

</script>
```

when I do a alert(myval) on the parent window I get the value I passed; 
However, I get the document.getElementById(...) is null. Do not understand why, please help me.

Comment: Please post the actual HTML, not PHP code.

Comment: You get `document.getElementById(...) is null` in your parent? Do you have an element with id `selecteditem` in parent? Also, can you try and keeping the 'name' & 'id' value of select option same?

Comment: Yes, the null is from the parent window. The 'selecteditem' comes from the id of the child window. I was following an example http://hspinfo.wordpress.com/2008/01/17/javascript-send-pass-value-of-child-window-to-parent-window/

Comment: What you're actually trying to do? First calling `window.opener.GetChildWindowInfo(myval);` and passing the wanted value, then in `GetChildWindowInfo()` trying to set the same value again... If you need to access the child window, you need to use a reference to it: `f.document.getElementById('selecteditem').value = myval;`. Though I can't understand why to do this, the value of `selecteditem` is already `myval`. Also some browsers might ignore setting a value of `select` element.

Comment: I just want to get the chosen value OR selecteditem and extract digits pretty much....I do get the myval correctly cause I can display myval using alert.... but I thought you had to get the id again and I'm getting null because it is an id from child window.

Comment: One more time: You've `f = window.open(...);` -->  `f.document.getElementById('selecteditem').value = myval;` ; ).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use cross document messaging:

child window:

```
function SendValueToParent()
{
    var myval = document.getElementById('selecteditem').value;
    window.opener.postMessage(myval, "http://example.com");
    window.close();
    return false;
}
```

parent window:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
        if(e.origin === "http://example.com/"){
            if(e.data){
                document.getElementById('selecteditem').value = e.data;
            }
        }
    }, false);
```